# JFET transconductance vs. MOSFET transconductance

Tags: mosfet, jfet, formula-derivation, transconductance

JFET's n-channel highest transconductance (from datasheets) is marked as [image]

In theory, the same value is defined as[image] that applies for n-channel JFET.

I haven't found equation which defines MOSFET's highest transconductance yet, so I'm wondering if the same equation can be applied except Up is switched with Ut - threshold voltage?

All I want is to somehow get "K" (conduction parameter) for MOSFET. Usually values like electron mobility parameter, oxide capacitance and W/L-ratio aren't given in datasheets so you have to calculate K in different way. For example, how would you calculate drain current in saturation mode, if K is unknown? Maybe through transconductance, but how if for calculating gm you need either drain current or conduction parameter?

Things are easier with JFET, where K is defined as K = Idss/Up squared. Both values here are given in all datasheets.

Comment: Most of the time, MOSFET and FET mean the same thing. There are also JFET's, and depletion mode MOSFET's. I think it would help if you provided a link to specific data sheets you are looking at, or specific part numbers.

Comment: @mkeith: Not part numbers but literature. I know what they are and their varieties but some equations just aren't the same for FET as for MOSFET.

Comment: Please define the terms FET and MOSFET. Your usage of these terms appears to be non-standard. Don't answer in the comments, edit in the question to make your question more clear.

Comment: Just a side note, next time when use equations when ask questions, try using LaTeX because sometimes mobile users can't see images that you post. [Here's a good place to look and see how to use LaTeX on SE.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @KingDuken: It would took a century for me to learn how to write a simple equation in language like this one

Comment: @mkeith: My explanation was just edited.